# What is the correct query for image order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which stores image path, related product id and image order.

Image order is using for sorting images in itself (i mean every product has more than one image). To clarify below structure is my image table

```
  img_id(autoincrement) | product_id(u.s int) | img_order(tiny int)
                   1000 |          1 |         0    
                   1001 |          1 |         1    
                   1002 |          1 |         2    
                   1003 |          2 |         0    
                   1004 |          2 |         1    
                    ---
                   1005 |          3 |         0   
                   1006 |          3 |         0    
                   1007 |          3 |         0    
                   1008 |          4 |         0    
                   1009 |          4 |         0
                   ...
```

As you can see after horizontal line every `img_order`'s value is **"0"**

***How can I handle only that rows with MySQL query? If I try `where img_order = 0`it not work because it includes img_id = 1000 (for example) but for product 1 it has none zero values for product's other images.***

I need only img_order = 0 rows but related product must not has img_order greater than zero

Comment: @Strawberry I work only this table, with which table should I use join

Comment: I think you're trying to return all rows for all `product_ids` that have no non-zero `img_orders`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using an outer join...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM product_images x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN product_images y 
             ON y.product_id = x.product_id 
            AND y.img_order <> 0 
          WHERE y.img_id IS NULL;
```

In addition to the PRIMARY KEY on img_id, I suspect that this query will benefit from an index on (product_id,img_order).

Comment: query working more than 2 minutes but still i cant see results. I have more than 200k rows and only img_id has index. How can reduce run time for this query?

Comment: @hakkikonu you need indexes on joining keys `both tables` and `img_order`

Comment: Not sure what @AbhikChakraborty means by `both tables`, but the principle of providing indexes is sound.

Comment: ı added index on (product_id,img_order) and it is in process. I'll notice you about result

Comment: Thanks now it is working 4x -6x faster. This is enough for me.

Comment: Ah @Strawberry my bad there is only one table :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
add index to product_id column and try this query

```
SELECT 
id
FROM
Table
WHERE
product_id IN (SELECT 
        product_id
    FROM
        Table
    GROUP BY product_id
    HAVING MAX(img_order) = 0)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but my table has more than 200k rows. Your query running more than 2 minutes but still I cant see results.

Comment: Provide info about your indicies if you want more relevant solution.

Comment: only img_id has index

Comment: How distinctive is your product_id field?

Comment: unsigned int - not null

Comment: I mean how many different values  product_id field can have? 5 different values out of over all 10 values?

Comment: Some products have more than 20 images so there is not a regular pattern

Comment: I add index but still changed noting. My VPS has 8gb ram and 4 core cpu so it is not problem. But index did not change anyting

index method : BTREE, index_type: normal

Comment: What does explain say?